# How to keep data separate with multiple root components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming, react-component

I'm building my whole site with React.js like this:

```
     React.render(
       <div id="mainWrapper">
         <MainHeader />
         <div id="contentWrapper" className="contentWrapper">
           <MainFlow data={example_data} />
           <AddElementWrapper data={activities} />
         </div>
       </div>,
       document.body
     );
```

However, calling setProperties on one of my data-holding components, namely MainFlow or AddElementWrapper, I get an error, stating that I should manipulate the data via their parents.

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: replaceProps(...): You called `setProps` or `replaceProps` on a component with a parent. This is an anti-pattern since props will get reactively updated when rendered. Instead, change the owner's `render` method to pass the correct value as props to the component where it is created.
```

First off: I thought that this would only be a problem if there is another *owner* for the component I want to manipulate. However, my components don't have React components as *owners*, just HTML elements as *parents*.

I could circumvent this problem by attaching ALL application data to a single root component. However, I'd like to keep certain sets of data separate. Is there a way?

Comment: Hint: wrap that in a component, and use event emitter to interact with the outside world.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I was thinking about that. However, I would like to keep the data logic from MainFlow and AddElementWrapper separate, since they are barely related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a Wrapper component and maintain the state of data there and simply invoke setState when data changes from the outside world.

```
Wrapper = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {example_data: example_data, activities: activities};
},
refresh: function() {
    this.setState({example_data: this.state.example_data, activities: this.state.activities});
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <div id="mainWrapper">
            <MainHeader/>
            <div id="contentWrapper" className="contentWrapper">
                <MainFlow data={this.state.example_data} />
                <AddElementWrapper data={this.state.activities} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

React.render(<Wrapper/>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the props to the state of the child component and then change the state.

In MainFlow and AddElementWrapper components you can use:

```
 getInitialState: function() {
  return {activities: this.props.data};
 },
```

Then you can use this.state.activities and modify it with setState({activities: yourObject })

Comment: Referring to props within the getInitialState is an Anti-Pattern : http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Comment: "However, it's not an anti-pattern if you make it clear that synchronization's not the goal" - From React's homepage( http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html ). In the above code he can't mutate the props from the paren't conponent since it is simple div tag with no methods attached.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using state now. I also wrapped my contents of #contentWrapper in an own component, since the data of MainFlow and AddElementWrapper is related but not linked.

Answer (score 1):

The idea will be to have React Components that explicitly listen to data changes. For that you will setup callback at your component mount.

I would suggest to look for two things : either Backbone+React (and the BackboneReact mixin) or Flux+React.

The flux way is to have a global events system about data availability (the dispatcher), and the the backbone way would be to register to a particular Collection events.

This code is directly from the BackboneMixin from the TodoMVC React-backbone project:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  // Whenever there may be a change in the Backbone data, trigger a
  // reconcile.
  this.getBackboneCollections().forEach(function(collection) {
    // explicitly bind `null` to `forceUpdate`, as it demands a callback and
    // React validates that it's a function. `collection` events passes
    // additional arguments that are not functions
    collection.on('add remove change', this.forceUpdate.bind(this, null));
  }, this);
},
```

More :

- Backbone+React example https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/react-backbone

Comment: Thanks! I finally decided to adopt the Flux way. However, I will have a look at Backbone+React, since I'm missing some of its richer model features.